# Default set of kryo registrations for spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I am running into a whack-a-mole with many classes requiring `kryo` registration. Is there a default registration for common `spark` classes that can help?

Here is a list of classes that I have had to add so far - and there is no end in sight:

```
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Row]))
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[InternalRow]))
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Array[InternalRow]]))
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1]))
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow]))
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType]]))
  conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer but is a partial explanation of the behavior. There was some older code that was forcing `kryo` to be particular:

```
 val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
```

I removed that line and then the "registration missing" complaints magically disappeared.